# how to change the values of label in listview from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listview, code-behind

Actually i'm developing template using asp.net and c#.
i'm using listview at my ascx page and my ItemTemplate is as below:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr style="background-color:#FFF8DC;color: #000000;">
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Product Details?');" />
        <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="True" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="EmpIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpID") %>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="EmpNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="DepartmentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Department") %>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="AgeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' />
    </td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and i retrieve the data from the database in ascx code behind as bellow:

```
public DataTable GetEmployee(string query)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable();
    ada.Fill(dtEmp);
    return dtEmp;
}
```

and also i bind the data in ascx code behind as follow:

```
private void BindLVP(string SortExpression)
{
    string UpdateQuery = "Select * from Employee" + SortExpression;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    hid_UpdateQTP.Value = UpdateQuery;

    lvProduct.Items.Clear();
    lvProduct.DataSource = GetEmployee(UpdateQuery);
    lvProduct.DataBind();
}
```

my question is how i can delete the `<%# Eval("EmpID") %>` and all the other label text like this in ItemTemplate and change the label.text in ItemTemplate from the code behind, i mean pass the data of the database to these label from code behind.
appreciate your consideration.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063311/how-to-set-label-text-inside-listview-from-code-behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx#Y630) event of the ListView what is fired for every item after you've bound the ListView to it's DataSource:

```
protected void LVP_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Label EmpIDLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("EmpIDLabel");

        System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        EmpIDLabel.Text = rowView["EmpID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This event is not triggered on every postback but only on databinding(unlike the ListView's [ItemCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcreated.aspx) event).