# Null exception in code behind

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am getting a null exception thrown.  Can you help me understand why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace ProjectEta
{
    public partial class File_Viewer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string CurDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {

                TextBox OpenDateTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("OpenDateTextBox");

                OpenDateTextBox.Text = "12/12/2012";

                DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
                string myCurDate = rowView["OpenDate"].ToString();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is the aspx.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
            <tr style="font-size: smaller; text-align: center;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ProcessorIdDrop" runat="server" DataSourceID="UserNames" DataTextField="Name" Text='<%# Bind("ProcessorId") %>' ></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="UserNames" DataTextField="Name" Text='<%# Bind("UnderwriterId") %>' ></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="FileStatusTypes" DataTextField="FileStat" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>' ></asp:DropDownList>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="OpenDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OpenDate") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="CloseDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CloseDate") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="BorrowerIdTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BorrowerId") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Lender_LenderIdDrop" runat="server" DataSourceID="LenderNames" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Text='<%# Bind("Lender_LenderId") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Client_ClientIdTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Client_ClientId") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
```

I followed the suggestion from this post, [how to set label text inside listview from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063311/how-to-set-label-text-inside-listview-from-code-behind) but I'm getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I thought since OpenDateTextBox was the ID of a text box in the aspx I wouldn't get this issue.  I get this is a noob question, but help would be appreciated.

Comment: One of the variables you're using contains `null`, probably because its initializer returns `null`. Let us know which line causes this.

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: Its also possible `e.Item.FindControl("OpenDateTextBox")` is returning null as it cannot find it.

Comment: Could you post the listview markup from the aspx page?

Comment: Is the OpenDateBox inside the listview as well?

Comment: I'm guessing it can't find e.Item.FindControl("OpenDateTextBox"), but why?

Comment: Because it's not there? If it was there, it would find it.

Comment: I can help: Learn how to use the debugger and/or copy error exact error messages and corresponding line of code so you're not asking everyone to guess.

Comment: @JonathanWood and others: there's just one place where he uses `OpenDateTextBox`, so it is not that difficult to see where the error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `NullReferenceException` because the `TextBox` is not inside of the `ItemTemplate` but the `InsertItemTemplate`. So you must check for `ListViewItemType.InsertItem` instead of `DataItem`:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    // note the ListViewItemType.InsertItem !!!
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.InsertItem)
    {

        TextBox OpenDateTextBox = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("OpenDateTextBox");
        OpenDateTextBox.Text = "12/12/2012";
    }
}
```

Note also that i've removed these lines:

```
DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
string myCurDate = rowView["OpenDate"].ToString();
```

Since there is no `DataItem` in the `InsertItemTemplate` (of course).

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the exception and lets the page render.  However when I do an insert I don't get the 12/12/2012 in the cell.  I'll dig into that a bit further.  Much appreciated, and thanks for being patient with the noobs.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue appears to be the selection of event.  I changed from ItemDataBound to ItemCreated and it worked just fine.  Thanks to those that provided guidance.